# How would you find the leg lengths on a right isosceles triangle when only given angles?

Tags: geometry

If I already know the angles since of right isosceles triangle (45-45-90), how can I determine the side lengths when I'm not given any information on them?

Comment: Do you know anything about the scale, for example the hypotenuse, or the perimeter or the area?

Comment: Use a ratio relative to the hypotenuse, i.e.,$ \frac {\sqrt 2} 2:1$.

Answer (score 1):

$(1,1,\sqrt2)$, $(\sqrt2,\sqrt2,2)$, among others, are $45^\circ$-$45^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangles.  You need more information to set the scale.

Answer (score 0):

The lengths of the triangle given satisfies an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your triangle is an isosceles, by definition two sides must be equal. Thus the legs are equal because the hypotenuse is always the largest part of the isosceles triangle.

There are infinitely many triangles that fit your description, as there is no AAA congruence rule in geometry.

However if both legs $(L)$ of your right triangle are equal. We can figure out how much larger the hypotenuse $(H)$ is by using Pythagorus theorem:

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

$$L^2+L^2=H^2$$

$$2L^2=H^2$$

$$2=\frac{H^2}{L^2}$$

Taking the negative square root will not make sense in this situation , so we only take the positive.

$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{H}{L}$$

Thus $H$ is $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.414$ times larger than $L$. If we know $L$ we can find $H$, and if we know $H$ we can find $L$. Also if we know $f(H)=L$ or $F(L)=H$ we can find what we need by substituting the function for the variable we have into our equation.